# typescript: Helper class with nested method with return

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I'm trying to create a JSON Helper class by calling method in top of another. i.e. second method take result from first method and process it. Also first method should give Class Object. If possible direct result.

Expected api and result from the Helper is as follow.

```
JSONMethods.parse("{name: 'hello'}") // { name: 'hello'}

JSONMethods.parse("{name: 'hello'}").format() // { name: 'hello'}

JSONMethods.parse("{name: 'hello'}").extract(Department); // { id: 0, name: 'hello'}
```

I've created a class as JSONMethods and defined those methods. but not sure how to progress. Find the code below.

```js
class Department {
    id: number = 0;
    constructor() { }
}

class JSONMethods {
    private static data;
    static parse<U>(json: string | U): JSONMethods {
        if (typeof json == 'string') {
            this.data = JSON.parse(json);
        }
        else {
            this.data = json;
        }
        return json; // not actually returing JSONMethods
    }

    static format() {
         return this.data;
    }

    static extract<T>(entity: T) {
         return Object.assign(new entity(), this.data); // getting compilation issue with new entity(). as *Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.*
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the result as above. Also, extract method should not available top of parse method not in JSONMethods. I can make it as private. But how to access extract method from parse.

Bit confused. Can anyone support on this.

Comment: hi prem, in your parse() function maybe your want to return this.data instead of json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in the constructor of the class not an instance of the class. So instead of `entity: T` it should be `entity: new () => T`

```
class JSONMethods {
    private static data;
    static parse<U>(json: string | U): typeof JSONMethods {
        if (typeof json == 'string') {
            this.data = JSON.parse(json);
        }
        else {
            this.data = json;
        }
        return this;
    }

    static format() {
        return this.data;
    }

    static extract<T>(entity: new () => T) {
        return Object.assign(new entity(), this.data); // getting compilation issue with new entity(). as *Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.*
    }
}

JSONMethods.parse("{name: 'hello'}") // { name: 'hello'}

JSONMethods.parse("{name: 'hello'}").format() // { name: 'hello'}

JSONMethods.parse("{name: 'hello'}").extract(Department);
```

Might I also suggest avoiding use of static fiedls in this case, you may run into troubles later if someone does not use the functions in the way you expect them to.

```
class JSONMethods {
    private data;
    static parse<U>(json: string | U): JSONMethods {
        var r = new JSONMethods()
        if (typeof json == 'string') {
            r.data = JSON.parse(json);
        }
        else {
            r.data = json;
        }
        return r;
    }

    format() {
        return this.data;
    }

    extract<T>(entity: new () => T) {
        return Object.assign(new entity(), this.data); // getting compilation issue with new entity(). as *Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.*
    }
}

let s = JSON.stringify({name: 'hello'});
JSONMethods.parse(s) // { name: 'hello'}
JSONMethods.parse(s).format() // { name: 'hello'}
JSONMethods.parse(s).extract(Department);
```